# Connection Refused Dockerised ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, docker, containers, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having some real pain in connecting to my dockerised ASP.NET Core Web API.

When I try to connect to it on `http://localhost:5000`, or `https://locahost:5001`, I just get

> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED (localhost unexpectedly closed the connection)

I'm very confused at this point and I feel like I have exhausted resources to try and solve the issue. I feel like it's going to be something trivial as a result.

Here are the files in question:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=thisisadifferentpassword
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

I thought it was certificate related, hence the certificates goodness. Have followed this documentation to implement this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the .NET SDK image as the build environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files for each part of your solution
COPY API/API.csproj ./API/
COPY Application/Application.csproj ./Application/
COPY Domain/Domain.csproj ./Domain/
COPY Persistence/Persistence.csproj ./Persistence/
COPY Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj ./Infrastructure/

WORKDIR /app/API

# Restore dependencies for the entire solution
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY ./API .
COPY ./Application ../Application
COPY ./Domain ../Domain
COPY ./Persistence ../Persistence
COPY ./Infrastructure ../Infrastructure

# Build your application
RUN dotnet build --configuration Debug

CMD ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I have tried adding EXPOSE 5000 or 5001 and had no luck with either of those, same problem.

When I run `docker-compose up --build` it successfully stands up, and says navigate to localhost:5001, but resulting in no success.

Is there something that I'm missing here? I appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001` and set `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to `http://+:5001` (or `http://+:5000,https://+:5001` if you need https) or fix the mapped port.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GuruStron.
Tried these points but continuing to get the same issue :( 
I've checked my firewall and there are no rules there which would prohibit traffic (I work on this port often, and have not had any problems).